# PyInstaller how to import gtk+?

Tags: python, gtk, python-import

I have a simple python app using Gtk 3,

```
#!/usr/bin/python
from gi.repository import Gtk

win = Gtk.Window()
win.connect("delete-event", Gtk.main_quit)
win.show_all()
Gtk.main()
```

but when I use PyInstaller stops working because he does not importing the library Gtk.

What can I do?

Comment: PyGObject is not a regular python module. It is only the binding for GObject Introspection.

Comment: @Gab: Are you trying to package for Windows?

Comment: Hi, @Gab, you solved it?

Comment: You have a solution? Post your answer.